# Driver or dll to simulate physical kinect sensor

Tags: c#, kinect

For the kinect development, is there a driver or dll that replaces the physical kinect sensor by using a web cam or something?
Or you have to have a kinect sensor? I don't have a x360, and i'm not too fond of the idea to buy just a kinect sensor...

Comment: A kinect isn't just a web cam. It has an IR projector and IR sensors.

Comment: I guess it can b helped then...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to have a Kinect sensor to develop with Kinect (if you want to test your programs), And like Quentin said it has much more than a VGA camera. It has a IR sensor, and 4 microphones. Also you don't need an Xbox to develop with Kinect, you can make desktop applications and windows games using XNA. If you end up developing with Kinect, I suggest you use the [Kinect SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/overview.aspx) with C#. Hope this helps!

Comment: You don't have to have a Kinect sensor.

Answer (score 5):

The libfreenect library includes [fakenect](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Fakenect) that lets you simulate a Kinect. You have to have a data set collected with the libfreenect 'record' program (plenty are available to download) and then you can test your algorithms offline.

Comment: As does the official Microsoft Kinect SDK as of version 1.5 via their Kinect Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Other solution is using Kinect Studio, but someone else have to record the streaming from a real kinect, but the size files are around GBytes.